# How to get data from Excel to Teradata table without using teradata olap connector

Tags: excel, excel-2007, teradata

My requirement is: I have to insert data from excel sheet to teradata tabels without using olap connector and import/export option thats available in TeraData.

Is this possible, if so could you please help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered the Teradata Studio product to perform JDBC FastLoads into empty staging tables.

Another option, albeit slower, would be to write VBA Macros with the .Net Provider or ODBC driver to process the ranges in Excel to load the data into Teradata.

Comment: Wanted to reduce the manual work, would be of great help if you let me know how to implement the above options (am new to teradata), thanks

Comment: What option are you going with and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I tried your suggestion of VBA Macros and it worked fine for my requirement,thanks.